# How to add a rollover effect to the text on a map

Tags: css

Ok so, I have this map:

[image: the map]

I need to add a rollover effect to the country names (this could be done with a simple :hover in CSS) but I can't find a good way to select just a portion of the text so if I hover "Europe" it just highlights Europe and not every word.

The image is in a PSD so I have access to the base map + layers. How could I approach this? I was thinking about adding all the text in HTML and style it in CSS (rotating, spacing and such), which would take ages, and it would also be a pain to manage when adapting for different resolutions.

Can you masters suggest anything? Thanks :)

The images for reference (text made red just to show there's something there, this would be the rollover effect):
[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some relevant code, at least upload the images and create a Fiddle. Asking for `best way to do it` (opinion) is too broad and does not meet SO standards.

Comment: I put the images at the bottom of the post, is this prohibited? I thought we could just use them hosted on SO servers. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/34av7k07/)'s where I am, basically I have no idea. I thought about asking here before doing the HTML/CSS only thing, which I worry might result in poor results in the first place.

Comment: Adding the text on html and give that style will, indeed, be a pain and a danger as fonts often changes on diff bwosers. I think the best way would be make an image of each text (I would use a sprite) and position the images over the map (text containers size and absolute position  top and left always in % if you want it responsive). of course it will take time. there's no easy way to do what you want.

Comment: Maybe you can use a `<map>` to define the different areas for your image. So you don't have to split your image and position each separately. Have a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: You cannot tag this question with javascript and css, because you look for **opinion**. I advice you add some code or the question will be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```css
body {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.states {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.map-container {
    width:960px;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    transform: scale(0.8);
}

a.state-name {
    position:absolute;
}

a.state-name:hover {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB42n.gif");
}
a#europe {
    background-position: -420px -140px;
    left: 420px;
    top: 140px;
    height: 45px;    
    width: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-container">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/319c9.gif" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB42n.gif" class="states" />
<a id="europe" class="state-name" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Note:

- you need to define for each country name a `a` tag and proper css rules: `background-position, width, height, left, top` like for `#europe` example
- `.map-container` - must have the same width as the original image 960px
- you need to use JS or CSS transform property to scale the whole `.map-container` if you need to resize the map, otherwise the hover elements will be misplaced.
- Pay attention to [css transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) properties

> **This is an experimental technology.** Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for the proper prefixes to use in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the spec changes.